# Stop Google Fonts from loading

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, fonts, content-security-policy

Currently in Germany, the chanche is high that sooner or later you get "sued" by certain attorneys which crawl websites with specially tweaked bots, looking for Google Font calls from the US Servers, because it violates the GDPR + TTDSG. A Wordpress Site of a client has sometimes many fancy premium plugins and themes, most of them use the `wp_enqueue_script` function but some of them have their custom approach to load Google Fonts, which are not covered by plugins designed to dequeue the calls.

Providing a local font is not that easy either. Although available, some plugins don't show them in the font selection.

What would be the most elegant way to disable those calls to the Google Servers?

**My approaches**

My initial thought was to create a Content-Security-Policy, only allowing 'self' as the default source. Prohibit everything and start allowing any resources you need, piece by piece. This is not that elegant for me - I only want to target Google Fonts, nothing else.

Installed plugins which block Google Font calls. As mentioned above: They can't fix custom functions.

Workaround with a cookie banner, paired with its content blocker functionality: If a user accepts the essential cookies a content blocker rule is triggered, blocking

1. *fonts.googleapis.com*
2. *ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js*
3. *fonts.gstatic.com*
4. *WebFont.load google*
5. WebFontConfig *google*

But the plugin currently does not allow to tie a content blocker to a essential cookie. Furthermore, it can't block content by accepting a cookie - the vice versa logic is not implemented.

---

Does php provide content blockerish methods, so that I could integrate them in the *functions.php* in Wordpress?

My dream would be to rewrite the URL as the call is about to go out(fonts.gooogleapis.com to gdprcompliantsource.fontapis.com), so that I don't have to tweak every template, plugin and theme.

Comment: "Does php provide content blockerish methods" - not really. You could turn on output buffering for everything and the rewrite the HTML, I guess. It actually might be easier to do it at the server ([Nginx](https://serverfault.com/a/713322)/[Apache](https://serverfault.com/a/684384)) level. The longer answer is that if someone purchased a theme with feature XYZ, and that feature is problematic, it might be time to get a new theme. I know money is an issue, but they'd have to way it against the possible legal issues

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but, why don't you just download/host the font locally?

Comment: Google will tend to serve content from its nearest data centre, which, for Germany, is likely to be in the Netherlands or Belgium. Since it's not possible to know where the request will go until its made, how do these attorneys know that request are going to the US?

Comment: @Joel I already did that. It does not fix the issue that some plugins or themes still have the call hardcoded somewhere.

Comment: Since googles servers choose the closest point to origin, if these are client-scripts it's out of your hands if you don't host it locally. It goes without saying, if you can't control other peoples plugins, there's not much for you to do here unfortunately. (unless u plug in edge-server functionality like Akamai provides) Then you can always route your traffic through a desired location.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular that may be true, they will still file a claim against you. Just because it's being likely that the content is served from servers in the EU does not mean for 100%. That is enough to file approx. 140 - 250€ from you.

Comment: Then akamai or cloudflare if your only option i'd say. Force your clients to be routed through a specific region (and probably server-side render the page as well).

Comment: What @Joel said. You should download the fonts locally and serve them from your own server so that you do not use Google's. WordPress is bringing this into core if I am not mistaken.